# Joist Hanger selection for 6x2 timbers

Tags: joists, shed, timber-framing

I am building a garden office, and the base is 6x2s

There seem to be a lot of options on which joist hangers to get. And quite huge price differences.

1. Multi Truss joist hanger 47x97 (approx £170 total)
2. Simpson Strong Tie THM230/44 (£47 total)
3. Cheaper timber-to-timber joist hanger that have long arms and bend over the top.

The Simpson Strong Tie are supposedly suitable, but they are so much cheaper that I’m dubious.

Stock of Multi Truss joist hangers seems to be hit and miss, and they are quite expensive. So I don’t want to spend if there’s no need.

It also seems a lot easier to get hold of 97mm height joist hangers, which I assume should be fine for a 6x2 (145mm actual height)

Timber is suspended on block piers.  It sitting on a solid base

Comment: I have not heard or read any bad things about the strong ties and they are usually a recommended choice.  Does your local building have any say about what you can use?  That is usually the most important knowledge.  As a shed they might not need to be involved, but they do have have local knowledge of what is recommended.

Comment: As it’s under 30sqm I can pretty much do what I want within reason. 

But it’s a good point, I could go quiz the local timber/builders merchant. 

The string ties say they are rated to 3.9kN and if i’m working that out right, that’s a lot.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t have knowledge of your expensive alternative, but Simpson has never disappointed.